# Floating images to the right of text in CSS below <h3> tags

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm not sure if anyone else has had this problem. I am trying place an image below an  headline (and above a paragraph) and float it to the right of the text and place a 10px margin to the left of the image. In my CSS style-sheet I have clearly selected the image and applied the 'float: right' property but the image still seems to stay on the left below the headline when I refresh the webpage.

The only solution I can find is in response to blog post ('floating right an image alongside an H3 tag'), - which suggests adding a  rule to the HTML after the image code. But this defeats the whole point of CSS. What if I want to apply this rule on multiple pages of my site?

My HTML is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet"href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="header" class="grid_11">
        <h1>Birthdays<h1>
        <h2>Perfect Fun-Philled Events<h2>
      </div>

      <div id="content">
      <div class="post">
        <img src="img/birthday cookie.jpg" class="pic">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam commodo imperdiet libero, id dapibus lorem viverra sit amet. Phasellus eleifend diam a erat viverra nec sodales orci feugiat Maecenas molestie nisl at erat lobortis commodo non nec lectus.</p>
        <p><a href="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_rwCJzc5dlWA/TPV7v1QQZsI/AAAAAAAAAjk/MgRY11AGuBA/s1600/PA300421.JPG">Original photo available here. </a></p> 
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 700px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#content .post {
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 4px solid #DA6;
    color: #420600;
}

#content .post h3 {
    margin: 0;
    color: #420600;
}

#pic {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
}
```

I would be grateful if anyone has any suggestions!

Comment: Your CSS defines style for item with ID pic `#pic`, but you've defined class pic. This means you must use `.pic` in your CSS stylesheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `#` which signifies `id`. You should use `.` for `class`, like so:

```
.pic {
float: right;
margin-left: 10px;
border: 4px solid #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can change the Image tag to

<img src="img/birthday cookie.jpg" id="pic"  alt ="alternate text" />

if you not use this any where in the page then it's better to use id than class  and always use alt tag to image.
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the original question which is related to the stylesheet.